Asymptotics of modified Bessel function of second kind
Let denote $K_\nu$ the modified Bessel function of second kind of argument $\nu\in(0,\infty)$. It is kown that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have:
$$K_\nu(x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} e^{-x}$$
as $x\to+\infty$. My questions are:

Is it also true for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ when $|z|\to\infty$ ?

If yes, do we have:
$$\mathrm{Im}[K_\nu(x)] = O\left(x^{-1/2} e^{-x}\right) ~\mathrm{and}~\mathrm{Re}[K_\nu(x)] = O\left(x^{-1/2} e^{-x}\right)\mathrm{?}$$


Thank you !

Try of the Gary answer:


For each fixed $\nu \in \mathbb C$, the function $z\mapsto K_\nu  (z)$ has a singularity at the origin. However, it is analytic on the Riemann surface associated with the logarithm. You can think of this surface as $\left\{z=r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} : r\in \mathbb R^+ ,\, \theta \in \mathbb R \right\}$. With the notation $\arg z=\theta$, the asymptotic approximation
$$
K_\nu  (z) = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2z}}} {\rm e}^{ - z} \left(1+\mathcal{O}\!\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)\right)
$$
is valid as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$). For a complete asymptotic expansion, see $(10.40.2)$.
Now, write
$$
K_\nu  (r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } ) = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } }}} {\rm e}^{ - r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } } \left( {1 + R(r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } )} \right),\quad \left| {R(r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } )} \right| = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{r}} \right).
$$
Then, using
$$
\left| {\operatorname{Re}R(r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } )} \right|,\;\left| {\operatorname{Im} R(r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } )} \right| \le \left| {R(r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } )} \right| = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{r}} \right),
$$
as $r\to+\infty$ and $|\theta|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$), we find that
$$
\operatorname{Re} K_\nu  (r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } ) = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2r}}} {\rm e}^{ - r\cos \theta } \left( {\cos \left( {r\sin \theta  + \frac{\theta }{2}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{r}} \right)} \right)
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Im} K_\nu  (r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } ) =  - \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2r}}} {\rm e}^{ - r\cos \theta } \left( {\sin \left( {r\sin \theta  + \frac{\theta }{2}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{r}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $r\to+\infty$ and $|\theta|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$). Note that in all these asymptotic results, $\nu \in \mathbb C$ is held fixed.
In particular, since
$$
\left| z^{ - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z}  \right| = r^{ - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - r\cos \theta } ,
$$
both $\operatorname{Re} K_\nu (z)$ and $\operatorname{Im} K_\nu (z)$ are $\mathcal{O}(z^{ - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z})$ as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$).
Addendum. A simpler argument that does not provide precise asymptotics is as follows. Note that
$$
\left| {\operatorname{Re}K_\nu  (z)} \right|,\;\left| {\operatorname{Im} K_\nu  (z)} \right| \le \left| {K_\nu  (z)} \right|,
$$
and that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to \infty } \frac{{\left| {K_\nu  (z)} \right|}}{{\left| {z^{ - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z} } \right|}} = \left| {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to \infty } \frac{{K_\nu  (z)}}{{z^{ - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z} }}} \right| = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{2}}  \Longrightarrow |K_\nu  (z)| = \mathcal{O}(z^{ - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - z}),
$$
as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$ ($<\frac{3\pi}{2}$).

Thank you @Gary for this great answer. However, when I plot the ratio in Mathematica, I can't get a clean convergence to 1.  The screenshot is in the post if you want to see.

Note that when you divide by the trigonometric factor, you have to divide the big-O term by it as well. However the trigonometric term has zeros and thus that error term can blow up. You should not do division. Instead, plot the actual value and the asymptotics separately, and see if the graphs mach with each other.

Alternatively, you can plot $$\left(\sqrt {\frac{{2r}}{\pi }} {\rm e}^{r\cos \theta } \operatorname{Re} K_\nu  (r{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta } ) \right)-\cos \left( {r\sin \theta  + \frac{\theta }{2}} \right).$$ This should me small for large positive $r$ in the range $|\theta|\le \frac{3\pi}{2}-\delta$.

All Bessel function have representations as $$f(z)= z^\alpha \ \sum_k \frac{1}{k!\ \Gamma(k + \beta)} z^k$$
It follows, that for integer $\alpha$ they are entier transcendental functions,  i.e. power series of infinite many, fast decaying but not 0-terminating series of coefficients, radius of  convergency $\infty$ .
In any punctured neighborhood of the point at infinity, these function assume all values $$f(z)\in \mathbb C$$  except for 2 values (Picard).
Stndard example
$$z\mapsto e^{\frac{1}{z}}= e^{\frac{1}{r (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)}} =e^{\frac{1}{r} (\cos \phi - i \sin \phi)} = e^{  \frac{1}{r} \cos \phi}*\left( \cos\left(\frac{1}{r}\sin \phi\right) - i \sin\left(\frac{1}{r}\sin \phi\right)\right)$$
indicating that for $r\to 0$ on any circle the values oscillate with frequency and argument going to $\infty$. Only  the two values $(0,\infty)$ are never assumed for $z\ne0$
This feature is evident for solutions of the wave euqation in two dimensions, because the separated 1-d real equations have oscillating exponential functions as solutions, that in the complex plane show this behaviour.

Thank you very much @Roland F for your answer, I have to admit that I didn't understand from your answer what was the answer to my post. Could you precise wether they are true or not please ? By the way, what do you mean by "0-terminating series" ?

The answer is that the special functions are finite on the real axis, where they occur in physics. As complex functions they are not approximable for large complex  z, because they are more than 'wildly' oscillating.  The term 'o-terminating series' of coefficients  means an infinite series that is finite, it generates a polynomial with all higher coefficients$a_k=0,  k\gt n$ zero. Polynomials and rational functions are the exceptional class of analytic functions with a definite pole or finite value at $z=\infty$

The $K$ Bessel function does not necessarily have an expansion of that form. For integer order, the expansion involves logarithms (cf. §10.31).

Algebraic eigenfunctions of selfadjoint operators of mathematical physics - mostly some forms of hypergeometric series solving a linear ODE of second order with maximal quadratic coefficients  in x -  are transcendental functions. Exceptions for normalizable eigenfunctions in the discrete spectrum in a finite domain, when the inifinte power series breaks off for special values of the parameter yielding polynomials. The secondary linear independent solution always includes a  log term, exhibiting its transcendental nature as the inverse of the exp at  the branch points $0, \infty$
